# Set MONTH in MYSQL based on another DATETIME value in the same row

Tags: mysql, date

I have two date fields in each row of the same table. I'm trying to figure out how to update just the MONTH of one date based on whether it is greater or less than the other date.

Here's what I need to execute: IF the second date is GREATER THAN the first date, then set the MONTH of the first date equal to the MONTH of the second date.

So if the first date is '2021-03-16' and the second date is '2021-05-01', I want to update the first date to equal '2021-05-16'.

Or, for a less verbose description, how do I transform this...

Data set:

```
id date_1       date_2
 1 2021-03-16   2021-05-01
 2 2021-03-16   2021-02-01
```

...into this...

```
id date_1       date_2
 1 2021-05-16   2021-05-01
 2 2021-03-16   2021-02-01
```

Any suggestions on the correct method/syntax to do this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
UPDATE table
SET first_date = CONCAT_WS('-', YEAR(first_date), 
                                MONTH(GREATEST(first_date, second_date)), 
                                DAY(first_date));
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can add to `date_1` as many months as is the difference of the months in the 2 dates:

```
UPDATE tablename
SET date_1 = date_1 + INTERVAL MONTH(date_2) - MONTH(date_1) month
WHERE date_1 < date_2
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=fcaf2b159fcb44666a74721ce0ca377a).
Results:

| id | date_1 | date_2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-05-16 | 2021-05-01 |
| 2 | 2021-03-16 | 2021-02-01 |

Note, that your requirement may fail in case of dates like `date_1 = '2021-03-31'` and `date_2 = '2021-04-30'` because this `'2021-04-31'` is not a valid date.
But the above query will work by changing the day also.

Comment: But in some cases the difference will be one month, in others it may be 2 or more, so I would need to add the interval based on the diff between the two dates, so not sure how that would work.

Comment: @JohnCallanan when the difference is 1 month then 1 month will be added, when the difference is 3 months then 3 months will be added, when the difference is -2 months then -2 months will be added. Didn't you try my code? You can't just change the month in a date value. It would crash your app if you try to change '2021-03-31' to '2021-04-31' .